# Joining qualified nouns

Tags: noun-phrases, conjunction-reduction

Is it ok to use "red and black buses and cabs" to mean "red and black buses and red and black cabs" for a city that has red buses, black buses, red cabs, and blacks cabs?

If not, what would be a better construction? And are there any formal writing guidelines/rules around this? Formal as in something documented in style guides such as Chicago Manual of Style?

Comment: I would use 'red buses and cabs, and black buses and cabs'. 'Red and black buses and cabs' to me means buses and cabs which are all painted in both red and black, perhaps red up to the bottom of the windows and black above.

Comment: Thanks, @BoldBen. That makes sense to me. Just updated the question as I am hoping to be on firmer ground here...

Comment: @WriteEquipped Knowing the context would be useful. I would use one formulation to describe street traffic in a novel, another for instructions in a tourist guide.

Comment: Yes, it means all four combinations in English. This is a common question here, but search is not helping much.

Comment: Consider "buses and cabs, some red, some black".

Comment: Also consider "a mix of red and black buses and cabs". Somehow, this doesn't elicit the two-toned vehicles that @BoldBen rightly pointed to as one interpretation of the plain "red and black buses and cabs" (no pun intended).

Comment: @Lawrence, thanks for your suggestions. They are valid, but not quite applicable in my context: a product data sheet. And the idea is to indicate that there are two variants of two products. Guess I should have provide this context earlier.

Comment: @WriteEquipped You still haven't provided it (the context). Give us the paragraph where this needs to be used.

Comment: @WriteEquipped You're welcome. Around here, answers tend to follow the lines of the question :) . It would be nice to have a "what the OP *really* wanted to ask" button, though. :P

Comment: @michael.hor257k sharing the paragraph in the next comment.

Comment: The current portfolio of Acme e-Vehicles has two product series: 
* Speed Series, which includes Red and Black buses and cabs. 
* Eco Series, which includes…

@BoldBen based on your suggestion, I have changed the first item to:

* Speed Series, which includes Red buses and cabs, and Black buses and cabs.

Comment: @BoldBen Is there a way I can give credit to you for this suggestion? If you could put your suggestion in an answer i could accept it. Is that the best way in this case?

Comment: I would humbly suggest: "Buses and cabs, in red and black".

Comment: @WriteEquipped Sorry it's been so long but thanks for asking for the comment as an answer. I didn't post it as an answer originally as it was an opinion, not something I could back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 'red buses and cabs, and black buses and cabs'. 'Red and black buses and cabs' to me means buses and cabs which are all painted in both red and black, perhaps red up to the bottom of the windows and black above.